# OrderBy in List on the basis of Dictionary Key-Value

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, key-value

I have the following List:

```
List<Student> list = 
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Student 1",
    "OtherInformation": {
      "hobby": "Music",
      "Score": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Student 2",
    "OtherInformation": {
      "hobby": "Golf",
      "Score": 70
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Student 3",
    "OtherInformation": {
      "hobby": "Archery",
      "Score": 30
    }
  }
]
```

`Other Information` is a Dictionary and I need to `OrderBy` the complete list using the dictionary Value which will be dynamic i.e. stored in some variable.

```
var sortKey = "id";
var propertyInfo = typeof(Student).GetProperty(sortKey);
list = list.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

I'm not able to do the above solution for Dictionary Key-Values such as `Score`

***Student.cs***

```
 public class Student
{
 public string Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public IDictionary<string, object> OtherInfomration{get;set;}
}
```

Help needed.

Comment: Why did you mix `List<Student> list` with plain JSON?

Comment: Please post your dictionary.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I haven't mixed, just wanna provide a view of my list

Comment: @canton7 The dictionary is already there in the list in the form of "OtherInformation".

Comment: Is it even compiled?

Comment: @JohnyL Yes it is

Comment: student.id is a string defined and list is having an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
var sortKey = "OtherInformation";
var propertyInfo = typeof(Student).GetProperty(sortKey);
list = list.OrderBy(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null))["Score"]).ToList();
```

Its not entirely clear why you're using reflection however.  You could easily just do this:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.OtherInformation["Score"]).ToList();
```

Comment: list = list.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)["Score"]).ToList(); gives out error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

Comment: see my edit.  Forgot the GetValue function just returns object so it needs to be cast

Comment: could you explain why you are using reflection?  Surely you deserialize your json into a list of student classes and then you can just use the second version above

Comment: The column name and sorting order is requested as: "id asc" or "OtherInformation.score". It is not known to the code that which column can be requested

Comment: ah i see, it does make sense in that case

Answer (score 0):

I made a mini console application using this data:

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         List<Student> list = new List<Student>()
            {
             new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "Student 1", OtherInformation = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                         {
                                             { "hobby", "Music" },
                                             { "Score",  "50" }
                                         }
                                     },
             new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "Student 2", OtherInformation = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                         {
                                             { "hobby", "Golf" },
                                             { "Score",  "70" }
                                         }
                                     },
             new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "Student 3", OtherInformation = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                         {
                                             { "hobby", "Archery" },
                                             { "Score",  "30" }
                                         }
                                     }
         };

         Console.WriteLine(list.OrderBy(x => x.OtherInformation["Score"]).FirstOrDefault().Name);
         Console.Read();
      }
 }
```

The result was Student 3 as wanted because he has the lowest score.

## EDIT:

Here you can use a pre-defined order statments:

```
public class OrderByStatment
{
    private string propertyName;

    public OrderByStatment(string propertyName)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public Expression<Func<Student, object>> GetOrderBy()
    {
        switch (this.propertyName)
        {
            case "id": return s => s.Id;
            case "name": return s => s.Name;
            case "score": return s => s.OtherInformation["Score"];
            case "hobby": return s => s.OtherInformation["hobby"];
            default: return s => s.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

calling it will be then:

```
Console.WriteLine(list.OrderBy(new OrderByStatment("id").GetOrderBy().Compile()).FirstOrDefault().Name);
Console.WriteLine(list.OrderBy(new OrderByStatment("score").GetOrderBy().Compile()).FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

You can absolutely make the code better by defining inheritance. Instead of new OrderByStatment("[propertyName]") you can use new IdOrderBy()

Hope that answers your question

Comment: I personally don't suggest to work with reflection (GetProperty) due to performance issues

Comment: In that case how can one can extract the order without knowing the column to be sorted upon

Comment: In this case, you have to use the reflection. So, adjust your query to be: list.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)["Score"]).ToList()

Comment: You just need to focus the sort on a specific key.

Comment: that won't work as well because it will throw error as ""Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' "

Comment: Another idea has popped into my mind is to use pre-defined order statements. Let me adjust the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.OtherInformation["Score"]));
```

Convert.ToInt32 is a bit dodgy as it can throw an exception.

Comment: Please read above, the situation is required for cases where Dictionary Name and Key Name is not known